# How to customize deserializer for third party Enum?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, deserialization

I have the following deseriailzer:

```
public class HttpStatusDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<HttpStatus> {

    @Override
    public HttpStatus deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        return HttpStatus.valueOf(node.asText());
    }
}
```

and register it

```
public class CustomDeserializerModifier extends BeanDeserializerModifier {

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
        if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() == HttpStatus.class) {
            return new HttpStatusDeserializer();
        }
        return deserializer;

    }
}
```

---

```
 mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
                .setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new SimpleModule()
                                                                           .setSerializerModifier(new CustomSerializerModifier())
                                                                           .setDeserializerModifier(new CustomDeserializerModifier())));
```

It doesn't invoke for enum but invoke for another classes.

How can I win this?

Comment: You have to annotate your enum class also and your deserialize method will also change. Can you provide your enum class to help you better?

Comment: @Aninda Bhattacharyya in question I mentioned that it is third party enum. This enum drom library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was resolved like this:

```
class MyClass{
    ...
    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK //from org.springframework.http
    @JsonIgnore
    public HttpStatus getHttpStatus() {
        return httpStatus;
     }

    @JsonProperty(value = "HttpStatus")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = HttpStatusDeserializer.class)
    public void setHttpStatus(HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
    }
    ....
}
```

and deserializer:

```
public class HttpStatusDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<HttpStatus> {    
    @Override
    public HttpStatus deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        return HttpStatus.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(node.asText()));
    }
}
```