# How to get the Enum value in serialised JSON from a Java object

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization

I have a Gender enum (which I can't edit) which is used in a Java class. Now, when I need to Serialise the Java class to JSON, I want the value of the Enum as part of the JSON and not the Enum name.  For example below in my enum, and when this enum is serialized, I want the value as `{"gender":"Male"}` I am using:

```
String underWritingJSONString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);

public enum Gender {
    MALE("Male"),
    FEMALE("Female");

    Gender(String gender) { 
        this.name = gender;
    }
    private String name; 

    String toValue() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

expected result = `{"gender":"Male"}`

current result = `{"gender":"MALE"}`

Following is the sample class

```
  public class MyObject {

    @JSONField
    public Gender gender;

    public MyObject() {

    }


    public Gender getGender() {
        return this.gender;
   }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned above, I can't edit the enum. It is part of anothe liberary. I need to either do some change in myObject class which is using this enum or in ObjectMapper settings

Comment: @ode-master-88 Your enum is not completed could you add/edit the enum(full declaration with methods) As it is accepting a paramete ther should be a constructor and is there a toString method by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

If enum has toString() method which returns the value then

```
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);
```

Is enough. But your enum don't have that as @Dinesh Kondapaneni mentioned you shold write a custom serializer like

```
class GenderSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Gender> {

@Override
public void serialize(Gender value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    if (null == value) {
    } else {
        try {
            gen.writeString(value.toValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
    }
}

}
```

And use it in your MyObject as

```
@JsonSerialize(using = GenderSerializer.class)
public Gender gender;
```

**FYI: Am using jackson here**

Comment: this should be selected as the correct answer . 

yes this is enough :`mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a method with annotation `@JsonValue`:

```
enum Gender {
    MALE("Male"),
    FEMALE("Female");

    Gender(String gender) { // constructor
        this.name = gender;
    }
    private String name; // variable

    @JsonValue
    String toValue() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This method will be called when you are serializing your object to JSON.

Comment: As mentioned above, I can't edit the enum. It is part of anothe liberary. I need to either do some change in myObject class which is using this enum or in ObjectMapper settings.

Comment: it is the same as your above sample without the @JsonValue annotation

Answer (score 0):

(Jackson 2.6.2 and above) you can now simply write:

```
public enum Gender {
 @JsonProperty("Male")
 MALE,
 @JsonProperty("Female")
 FEMALE
  }
```

Comment: As mentioned above, I can't edit the enum. It is part of anothe liberary. I need to either do some change in myObject class which is using this enum or in ObjectMapper settings

Comment: will it be helpful for you? [Enum Custom Deserilization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747977/how-to-customize-deserializer-for-third-party-enum/31755091#31755091)